# Getting the ligatures in Wyld to work

Tags: ligatures

The Caslon revival Wyld

http://orbitals.com/programs/wyld.zip

has ligatures, but I can't get them to work. I tried moving them to the standard unicode position with fontforge, and even added `\fontspec[featurefile=wyld.fea]{Wyld}`:

```
languagesystem DFLT dflt ;
languagesystem latn dflt ;
feature liga {
       sub f i by uniFB01;
} liga ;
```

but to no avail. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standards have developed since this font was created, so it needs lots of editing to be used well and with ease today.  In the case of the roman face, I’ve done some of what’s either necessary or desirable (conversion from TrueType to PostScript-flavored OpenType, re-encoding of the numerous incorrectly encoding glyphs so that searching and copying will work, adjustment of the em size, etc.), but there’s more to be done, especially the addition of features, and I haven’t touched the italic.

You will find the roman face as edited on [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ir7tv61frjoznpt/AAAszS0MRNro-tRP_7jR4zZ7a?dl=0).  With that, this test works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,fontspec,microtype}
\begin{filecontents*}{wyld.fea}
languagesystem DFLT dflt;
languagesystem latn dflt;

feature liga {
  sub \f \f by \ff;
  sub \f \i by \fi;
  sub \f \l by \fl;
  sub \f \f \i by \ffi;
  sub \f \f \l by \ffl;
} liga;
\end{filecontents*}
\setmainfont{Wyld}[
  FeatureFile=wyld.fea]
\begin{document}
The five fluffy officials were baffled.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of test]

Libre Caslon is included in TeX Live; there’s also a Libre Caslon Display from [Impallari](http://www.impallari.com/). They may be suitable for your work, unless you need the less finished appearance of Wyld.  You might also consider Junicode, which is based on a 17th-century English design; it’s earlier than Caslon, but moving in the direction of Caslon.

I don’t much like Caslon, so anyone with an interest in this font should feel free to push along what I started.

Comment: Thank you, Thérèse, for the improvement of Wyld and for mentioning Junicode, which also has very nice Greek letters, and seems to be full of features.